# Fantasy movie about two characters trying to defeat a villain able to possess people. They walk through a forest and visit a monastery

Tags: story-identification, movie

### Setting

A fantasy world with invented places (that is, not a fantasy version of our real world). A medieval equivalent setting (swords, torches, horse-riding and the likes).

The movie itself was probably released between 1990 and 2005. Definitely before 2010.

### The protagonists

There are two protagonists in the movie. They both are white human males around 20 to 30 years old, that start the movie as friends or neighbors.

They most likely lived on a small village or town. Definitely not on a big city or fortress.

I don't remember them having any kind of important profession or occupation at the start of the movie. They were probably farmers or other type of generic medieval job.

### The villain

This villain can transform or otherwise use a raven, crow or similar black bird to move or extend his influence undetected. He is also able to temporarily possess people, which causes the victim to acquire "evil makeup" like Bilbo Baggins and become aggresive.

He must have some kind of minions or underlings, possibly orcs or some similar monstruous creatures that don't communicate other than grunting and yelling.

### The plot

Somehow, the protagonists embark in an adventure to defeat the villain and save the world.

It's possible that some kind of elderly mentor figure was involved in this decision, but I'm not really sure.

Their journey takes them to several places, including the following scenes:

#### Forest

At one point both protagonists are walking through a lush forest during the day, one ahead of the other. One of them is wearing a black or brown hooded cape that hides his face. Soon, the second character realizes that something is wrong (possibly after seeing the black raven flying nearby).

He gets close to his hooded friend, and a "jumpscare moment" reveals that the villain has possessed him. He turns around and attacks the second character, who manages to fight long enough for the possession to expire.

#### Monastery

Some time after the forest scene, the two protagonists reach some sort of monastery or temple, built next to, or on top of a mountain. This monastery is inhabited by a group of nuns or priestessess that belong to the same order or organized group, and seem to take their job very seriously. After being granted entry, the two protagonists meet a young priestess named "Sister Telar" or "Sister Velar" or something like it.

One of the protagonists seems to take a liking to this priestess, and his friend is disapproving at first. An older, higher-ranking nun also seems to dislike this fact. Nevertheless, they are allowed to stay inside the monastery.

After that, maybe at night, something leads to the two protagonists and the young priestess to investigate some kind of caves or tunnel system below the monastery, using torches to light their way. It's possible that the villain is using the tunnels to launch an attack, or maybe they are looking for some artifact or weapon to use against him.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Parts of this sound like a garbled version of "A Wizard of Earthsea". Could it have been the two-part minseries, "Earthsea", from 2004? Could the prietess' name have been "Tenar"?

Comment: If the Earthsea miniseries (2004) is correct, possession scene in forest described in question is at about 1h14m of episode 1.